# Retrieve just the month and year from database date column

Tags: php, database, date

I stored the date (October 18, 2013 1:38am) with the following code to my database, now I just want to retrieve the month (eg. October, 2013) from the date in my database. please help.

```
$date = date("F j, Y g:i a");

    //insert into SQL code here
    $insert_sql = "INSERT INTO walls(upload_date) VALUES ('{$date}');";
```

insert into database

```
mysql_query($insert_sql)
        or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Why are you storing dates as strings instead of as datetime?

Comment: You should be storing the dates as a `DATETIME`, not a string

Comment: amm because that is how I want it to be outputted later, the output should be October 18 only.

Comment: But it makes it really hard to manipulate, compare, etc. You can always use formatting functions when you want to output it.

Comment: ah ok..and we can just manipulate when retrieving the date.

Comment: hi again! could you please provide sort of simple tutorial showing how to store it as DATETIME..would be lot appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will do it:

```
SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(upload_date, LOCATE(" ", upload_date)-1), ", ",
              SUBSTR(upload_date, LOCATE(", ", upload_date)+2,
                                  LOCATE(" ", SUBSTR(upload_date, LOCATE(", ", upload_date)+2)))) month_year
FROM walls
```

If you instead stored it as a `DATETIME`, it would be:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(upload_date, "%M, %Y") month_year
FROM walls
```

Comment: how will I be able to store it to database, as I'm getting an error. please help. thanks a lot!

Comment: Either pass the date in the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format, or use the `STR_TO_DATE()` function to parse the date in the format you supply.